# How to inject/configure user model for setting relationships in loopback 4 component?

Tags: model, overriding, relationship, loopbackjs, configure

As per DRY, I'd like to contain my business logic in extension (loopback component).
However, when defining models I'd like to specify belongsTo relationship to a property.

**In LB3, I'd do the same by defining the following module and override via configuration:**

```
module.exports = (blogModels, options) => {
  const debug = require('debug')('component:blog:postlike:model');
  const {userModel} = options;
  const postLikeModel = blogModels.PostLike;
  const postModel = blogModels.Post;

  // update relationships
  postModel.belongsTo(userModel,
    {as: 'userCreated', foreignKey: 'createdBy'});
  postModel.belongsTo(userModel,
    {as: 'userDeleted', foreignKey: 'deletedBy'});
  postModel.belongsTo(postModel,
    {as: 'post', foreignKey: 'postId'});

  let postLike = {};
  return postLike;
};
```

### Also, I'd like to know how can I let developer specify the model in case he wants to specify a custom one.

**In LB3, this would be done like this.**
https://github.com/pbalan/component-blog/blob/master/lib/models/index.js#L51-L63

```
const debug = require('debug')('component:blog');
const accessLogger = require('../middleware/access-logger');
const userContext = require('../middleware/user-context');
const logger = require('../middleware/logging');
const reqLogger = require('../middleware/request-logging');

module.exports = function componentBlog(app, options) {
  debug('initializing component');
  const {loopback} = app;
  options = options || {};

  let dataSource = options.dataSource;
  /* istanbul ignore if */
  if (typeof dataSource === 'string') {
    dataSource = app.dataSource[dataSource];
  }
  const blogModels = require('./component-blog-models')(dataSource);
  const userModel = loopback.findModel(options.userModel) ||
      loopback.getModelByType(loopback.User);
  debug('User model: %s', userModel.modelName);

  const venueModel = loopback.findModel(options.venueModel);
  // debug('Venue model: %s', venueModel.modelName);

  // Initialize middleware
  app.middleware('initial:before', logger());
  app.middleware('initial:before', reqLogger());
  app.middleware('auth:after', userContext());
  app.middleware('routes:before', accessLogger());

  let users = {};
  let venue = {};

  let internalConfig = {
    userModel: userModel,
    venueModel: venueModel,
  };

  // specific to app
  const post = require('./Post')(blogModels, internalConfig);
  const postLike = require('./PostLike')(blogModels, internalConfig);
  const postMention = require('./PostMention')(blogModels, internalConfig);
  const postShare = require('./PostShare')(blogModels, internalConfig);
  const postComment = require('./PostComment')(blogModels, internalConfig);
  const commentComment =
    require('./CommentComment')(blogModels, internalConfig);
  const postMedia = require('./PostMedia')(blogModels, internalConfig);
  const blogReported = require('./BlogReported')(blogModels, internalConfig);

  let customModels = options.models || {};
  let models = {
    user: customModels.users || users,
    venue: customModels.venue || venue,
    blogReported: customModels.blogReported || blogReported,
    post: customModels.post || post,
    postLike: customModels.postLike || postLike,
    postMention: customModels.postMention || postMention,
    postShare: customModels.postShare || postShare,
    postComment: customModels.postComment || postComment,
    commentComment: customModels.commentComment || commentComment,
    postMedia: customModels.postMedia || postMedia,
  };

  return models;
};
```

**Then, in a boot script, we could provide the necessary overrides.**

https://github.com/pbalan/component-blog/blob/master/test/fixtures/simple-app/server/boot/003-component-blog.js#L7

```
module.exports = function blog(app) {
  var blog = require('../../../../../lib');

  var options = {
    // custom user model
    userModel: 'user', // specify your custom user model
    uploadMediaUrl: '/api/containers/blog-media/upload',
    baseUrl: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000',

    // Data source for metadata persistence
    dataSource: app.dataSources.db,
  };
  app.set('component-blog', options);
  blog(app, options);
};
```

### I'm looking for a similar example for LB4. Unfortunately, current examples mostly reflect applications instead of components.

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to achieve here ? I have done similar stuff, so may be I can help. Let me know the use case. You basically want dynamic models ?

Comment: @Samarpan yes dynamic models such that developer could specify the User model while configuring the component. For example, a developer calls his User model, MyCompanyUser, then he would like to override the base User with MyCompanyUser and also the same with repository.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the new authentication component? https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Loopback-component-authentication.html

It has a binding that rescues the authenticated user of the endpoint. Just inject the user in the controller's constructor (I'm not sure if injecting it in the endpoint works)

```
import {SecurityBindings, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';
```

```
 @inject(SecurityBindings.USER)
    private userProfile: UserProfile,
```

A simple example (extracted from the official docs, it's in the link I put at the top):

```
import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
import {AuthenticationBindings, authenticate} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {SecurityBindings, securityId, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';
import {get} from '@loopback/rest';

export class WhoAmIController {
  constructor(
    // `AuthenticationBindings.CURRENT_USER` is now an alias of
    // `SecurityBindings.USER` in @loopback/security
    @inject(SecurityBindings.USER)
    private userProfile: UserProfile,
  ) {}

  @authenticate('basic')
  @get('/whoami')
  whoAmI(): string {
    // `securityId` is Symbol to represent the security id of the user,
    // typically the user id. You can find more information of `securityId` in
    // https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Security
    return this.userProfile[securityId];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am not using loopback authentication component. In fact, I have a scaffold here based off sourcefuse starter kit. https://github.com/pbalan/loopback4-starter-mysql. Besides I think I am looking to find how should I specify related model.

Comment: Maybe the relation resolver can help you. For example a use case is If you want a blog model to have a reference (belongs_to) to user model. For now, Lb4 has a cli to help you to do that. You can query the related model with the correct filter, for example: 
{
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 100,
  "skip": 0,
  "include": [
    {
      "relation": "user",
      "scope": {
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 100,
        "skip": 0,
      }
    }
  ]
}
If was that the case, I will update my answer